# NextJS Lighthouse Best Practices: Properly defines charset Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, seo, lighthouse

I get this error on my blog page:
Properly defines charset Error! A character encoding declaration is required. It can be done with a  tag in the first 1024 bytes of the HTML or in the Content-Type HTTP response header. Learn more about declaring the character encoding.

I do not get this error on my index page and other pages despite having `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` on the page.

My _document.js:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="ja">
        <Head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

The error goes away when I reduce the amount of data that is returned from the getserversideprops on my blog page. Does this relate with the Properly defines charset error?

If it does, I would return some data from the client side but that would affect the SEO.

How can I resolve this issue?

I tried reducing the amount of data returned from the MySQL Database in the getserversideprops and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing that large pages trigger this error, while smaller pages from different parts of the site do not. I think it is a Lighthouse bug.